# Quick look .url saved webpages as rendered HTML

Tags: finder, safari, macos, quicklook, library

I thought this was already possible in earlier versions of OS X but Yosemite seems to be missing the 'Web.qlgenerator' quick look plugin (or at least I am)

How do you enable .url quick look to see rendered html in Yosemite?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802873/quicklook-html-files-as-text-not-rendered-html) of someone who wants to disable the rendered html and have it show to source code instead, so it should be possible

Answer (score 1):

Quick Look doesn't make web requests, so it can't show the contents of the webpage without opening it. The question you linked was asking about `.html` files, with the actual source saved locally. `.url` files only include a URL, so without downloading the page it can't render anything. You can still use `.html` or `.webarchive` files and they will be rendered in Quick Look (with a `.webarchive` everything, including images and styles, will be included).